Differences between Requests and AIOHTTP when constructing an http request
I am trying to learn asynchronous programming in Python.
I have a simple get request that returns status code 200 when using the Requests modules.
When trying to reproduce the same request using AIOHTTP, I get a 403 status code response.
My question is : How does AIOHTTP differentiate itself from Requests when it comes to constructing an http request?
I believe that since I am passing the same parameters to both requests, there might be differences in the way the requests are sent, resulting in the AIOHTTP request failing.. Possibly something to do with the headers or cookies..
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import requests

url = "https://spectate-web.888sport.com/spectate/sportsbook-req/getTournamentMatches/ice-hockey/united-states-of-america/nhl"

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36', 
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 
    'Accept': '*/*', 
    'Connection': 'keep-alive', 
    'Cookie': 'odds_format=DECIMAL; optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1712128176635r0.5640445223678774; _cs_c=0; FPID=FPID2.2.p9QFQEw3wxQgGubYSYQTLEyXHhaPlG6hnxGm5JhFQZs%3D.1712128177; OptanonAlertBoxClosed=2024-04-03T07:09:47.833Z; _gcl_au=1.1.303053898.1712128188; OptanonConsent=isGpcEnabled=0&datestamp=Wed+Apr+03+2024+00%3A09%3A47+GMT-0700+(Pacific+Daylight+Time)&version=202209.2.0&isIABGlobal=false&hosts=&consentId=9f33e415-6ad2-41d4-9ce8-5aa5d4b9c619&interactionCount=1&landingPath=NotLandingPage&groups=C0001%3A1%2CC0002%3A1%2CC0003%3A1%2CC0004%3A1; FPAU=1.2.1880634315.1712128189; __qca=P0-1150796283-1712128188063; blueID=b6302533-2e9a-4ce6-8220-9c82c65df18a; _fbp=fb.1.1712128192008.2093727263; _scid=fd08dc38-6af8-4912-d93b-898a1a94bc17; login_deviceuuid=37d22c5f-2f3e-4dff-a627-879c9dc45870; anon_hash=05c6744a8af2029e8018973278168195; spectate_session=780bc31d-1423-4820-955e-2c1bff1e598a%3Aanon; 888Attribution=1; 888Cookie=lang%3Den%26OSR%3D1927680; 888TestData=%7B%22strategysource%22%3A%22previousvisit%22%2C%22currentvisittype%22%3A%22Unknown%22%2C%22referrer%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F%22%2C%22orig-lp%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.888sport.com%2Fbaseball%2Funited-states-of-america%2Fmajor-league-baseball-t-324139%2F%22%2C%22publisher%22%3A%22SearchEngine%22%2C%22strategy%22%3A%22UnknownStrategy%22%2C%22datecreated%22%3A%222024-05-09T18%3A46%3A37.924Z%22%2C%22expiredat%22%3A%22Thu%2C%2016%20May%202024%2018%3A46%3A00%20GMT%22%2C%22datemodified%22%3A%222024-05-13T23%3A59%3A03.232Z%22%2C%22modifiedcounter%22%3A%224%22%7D; spectate_client_ver=2.71; bbsess=zi4-oo0BBzStlX6jecq76Ohha-x; lang=enu; _cs_cvars=%7B%7D; _gid=GA1.2.388250393.1715644745; _gat_UA-125725186-7=1; FPGSID=1.1715644745.1715644745.G-15CNXYXJ7R.lERb7naix8ZqN0n-RV2TSA; FPLC=os%2FV%2FxiV%2BsUjh9NAS1aCO6Z7OGcyMwfxMEOAXXjQ8fFn2TwmxnMIS3TNIde0PK%2B5Exqd5ou1ztzKH5uqLKIXj9Yt%2Bk7DCeFKK7ni9z%2Bx1LCHs%2FzC6WTKZkn4EoIUjQ%3D%3D; _cs_id=8ce8877b-5380-a03e-ec85-8434a4d28294.1712128178.29.1715644748.1715644744.1708336297.1746292178098.1; _cs_s=2.5.0.1715646548363; _uetsid=c6fa0430118411ef9efc39c590568d56; _uetvid=5ac21390f2fd11ee87406f760e46580c; _ga=GA1.2.957392554.1712128177; _ga_15CNXYXJ7R=GS1.1.1715644744.30.1.1715644756.0.0.1631588786'
}

resp = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
print(resp.status_code)
#Output 200

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url, headers=headers) as response:
            print(response.status)

asyncio.run(main())
#Output 403

I have tried printing the headers of both requests to make sure they are identical using
print(resp.request.headers) for Requests
and print(response._request_info) for AIOHTTP
I noticed the header "Host" was automatically added by Requests but not by AIOHTTP.
After adding it manually in the headers, I am still getting error 403.
What else should I look into?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Try looking at the raw request being sent. e.g. Run nc -l 8000 and then make the request to http://localhost:8000 to see the raw message being sent (nc comes from the netcat-openbsd package in Ubuntu, or similar package elsewhere).

It's unusual to set the Cookie header directly, so it might be that aiohttp ends up replacing it or encoding it or something. If that is the case, trying setting the cookie the conventional way: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#custom-cookies

Thank you Sam Bull. I will have a look at the raw requests and see if I can differentiate them. I put the cookie originally in the conventional way, but noticed that one library (either aiohttp or requests, I forgot which one ) was automatically transferring the cookie to the headers in the construction of the request. I put in the headers so that both requests would be identical, unfortunately that didn't help.
